# Ежедневная миграция данных с SQL Server на Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, миграция, integration-services

Ситуация заключается в том что есть две идентичные базы, но одна на SQL Server, а другая на Oracle. Сейчас так обстоят дела, что ежедневно я вручную кидаю все "новые" данные в "шаблон" инсерта с SQL Server и вставляю их в Oracle, но я считаю что все что можно автоматизировать, нужно автоматизировать =)
К сожалению опыт у меня пока пол года и на данный момент не имею особого представления как такое сделать, мог бы мне кто-то подсказать варианты исполнения?
Я что-то слышал о Integration Services, но только слышал...
Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает! если есть какие-то вопросы более подробные, спрашивайте, постараюсь ответить)

Comment: Расскажу, как у меня реализована ежедневная миграция, но наоборот, с Oracle на Sql Server. На Sql Server создан Linked Server, хранимые процедуры, которые через openquery подключаются к этому серверу, вытаскивают данные и кидают их в таблицы. Выполнение этих процедур прописаны в Sql Server Agent(то есть созданы jobы). Скорее всего, подобное можно реализовать и в обратном порядке, но с ораклом знаком не так хорошо

Comment: А еще есть такая штука как Oracle Golden Gate, универсальное средство репликации данных между любыми реляционными БД. Но в нее надо вкурить как следует, что бы настроить

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень общий. Попробуйте разделить задачу на отдельные части  и искать пути решения для каждой из них. Пока из вопроса просматривается простое решение: _ежедневно я вручную кидаю все "новые" данные в "шаблон" инсерта _ - если это работает, то  не делайте это вручную, напишите скрипты и запускайте их как jobs.